# Sortable object list with O(1) deletion of the first element

Tags: delphi, collections

For Delphi (2009 or newer), is there an implementation of an object list with these two features:

- allows custom sorting
- performs deletions of the first list element in O(1) time

Comment: I took a quick look through the source (Delphi 7) and the implementation was definitely O(n) for removal of the first element. That being said, this wouldn't be that hard to write if you just extended TAbstractList using a basic list implementation. Honestly I'm not sure why it isn't O(n) out of the box... good luck.

Comment: Here is a [delphi generic collection library](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-coll/wiki/CollectionDetails) with TObjectLinkedList, which handles sort. There is also a TPriorityQueue, but you will have to implement the sorting yourself.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing that ships with the product that has those properties. The obvious and simple solution is to reverse the indexing of the list so that when you delete the first element the code actually deletes the last element of the underlying list.

To give you an idea of what I'm getting at, here's the sketch of the beginnings of a very basic implementation. It would need a lot of work to bring to completion.

```
type
  TMyObjectList<T> = class
  private
    FList: TObjectList<T>;
    function GetItem(Index: Integer): T;
    function ReversedIndex(Index: Integer): Integer;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Items[Index: Integer]: T read GetItem; default;
    procedure Delete(Index: Integer);
  end;

function TMyObjectList<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FList := TObjectList<T>.Create;
end;

destructor TMyObjectList<T>.Destroy;
begin
  FList.Free;//don't use FreeAndNil because it offends Nick Hodges  ;-)
  inherited;
end;

function TMyObjectList<T>.ReversedIndex(Index: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := Count-1-Index;
end;

function TMyObjectList<T>.GetItem(Index: Integer): T;
begin
  Result := FList[ReversedIndex(Index)];
end;

procedure TMyObjectList<T>.Delete(Index: Integer);
begin
  FList.Delete(ReversedIndex(Index));
end;
```

I'm assuming that you want an array as your underlying storage because I'd guess that you want O(1) random access.

All the other functions that you need, that use an index parameter would also need to call `ReversedIndex`. The most tricky thing to write would be the sort routines. The classes in `Generics.Collections` use `IComparer<T>`. You would do the same but then delegate the sorting to `FList` passing a locally constructed comparer `IComparer<T>` that reversed the results of the comparer provided by the caller.

Comment: + 1 for showing me that I could have solved it just by an upside-down use of a regular list, by removing at the end instead of the beginning of the list. But then I realized that I had made a third assumption - that adding to the end has to happen in O(1) too. But then I can not use this clever solution but need some kind of double-linked-list.

Comment: Now you are changing the rules of the game! O(1) both ends and fast sorting is hard. Sorting linked lists is not easy. Do you want random access to be fast?

Comment: A priority queue similar to [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) in mind. Actually my target is moving rapidly, adding to an ordered queue does not occur at the end but new items will be inserted based on the sort order :) (it is part of an object caching solution)

Comment: You can always use a Linked List and sort with merge sort.